# javascript iteration within if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3jaapj5/8/) (with the problem code commented out) the first click in an empty cell sets a value in a hidden input and sets the bgcolor of the cell to green. A click in a second empty table cell sets the value of another hidden input and changes the second cell bgcolor to red.

Now, based on feedback from another SO question I have tried to implement a check by looping through an array (All the commented out code) of all td's in the table to see if onclick, any cell already has a bgcolor set to green/red respectively and if true, set the bgcolor to empty/blank to allow for the NEW cell selection to get the bgcolor , so there should always be only 1 green block and 1 red block. Can someone explain to me how I am implementing the loop and check wrong and not getting the expected result.

the array looping works [here -jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ugf3otw/1/) when not part of the existing code. But when I add it to code where it's needed, it does not work.

HTLM

```
<div id="starget"></div>
<div id="etarget"></div>

<table width="100%" id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tech</th>
            <th>0800</th>
            <th>0900</th>
            <th>1000</th>
            <th>1100</th>
            <th>1200</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Bill</td>
        <td>XXX</td>
        <td onclick="res(0900,this);"></td>
        <td>XXX</td>
        <td>XXX</td>
        <td onclick="res(1200,this);"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

SCRIPT

```
var x = 0;
var click = 0;

/* tdElements = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); */
/* I have tried the tdelements array inside and outside of the function */

function res(zz,el) {
    if (click == 0) {
        /* for(var key in tdElements) { 
            if (tdElements[key].style.backgroundColor=="green") {
                tdElements[key].style.backgroundColor="";
            }
        } */
        document.getElementById('starget').innerHTML=zz;
        click = 1;
        el.style.backgroundColor='green';
    }
    else {
        /* for(var key in tdElements) { 
            if (tdElements[key].style.backgroundColor=="red") {
                tdElements[key].style.backgroundColor="";
            }
        } */
        document.getElementById('etarget').innerHTML=zz;
        click = 0;
        el.style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` loops for iterating through arrays or array-like objects. Use a numeric index.

Comment: @Pointy the actual table in live code (not these jsfiddle examples)  may be 100+ td's and is dynamically created, so i do not know how many td's would be in the array index. I will have to iterate over it somehow one way or the other.

Comment: You do know, because the `.length` property of the node list returned from `getElementsByTagName()` will tell you.

Comment: @Pointy so your advocating that if the `.length` returns lets say 5o that I should write this check `document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.backgroundColor=="green";` 50 times?

Comment: NO - Use a `for` loop with a numeric index - `for (var i = 0; i < tdElements.length; ++i)` and operate on `tdElements[i]`

Comment: Actually you guys are missing the issue. Gimme a moment.

Comment: @somethinghere I didn't mean for it to turn into a debate :)

Comment: @pointy didn't mean that, just wanted to say you are right - a `for` loop is better, mostly because a `for .. in` loop includes the `item()` function that `getElementByTagName` returns :) Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to be doing is handling this with a `class`, rather than a `style`.  The reason is that you can very easily pull up all of the elements that have a specific class using `getElementsByClassName` (**note:** in IE 9 and later).

Without deviating from your approach TOO much (I did make it a little more efficient   :)   ), your code would need to change to:

**CSS:**

```
.firstClick {background-color: green;}
.secondClick {background-color: red;}
```

**Script:**

```
var click = 0;

function res(zz,el) {
    var currentlyClickedEls, currClass, divTarget;

    if (click === 0) {
        currClass = "firstClick";
        divTarget = "starget";
        click = 1;
    }
    else {
        currClass = "secondClick";
        divTarget = "etarget";
        click = 0;
    }

    // get all the elements with the appropriate class
    currentlyClickedEls = document.getElementsByClassName(currClass);

    // remove that class from those elements
    while (currentlyClickedEls.length > 0) {
        currentlyClickedEls[0].className = "";
    }

    // add the class to the clicked element
    el.className = currClass;
    document.getElementById(divTarget).innerHTML = zz;
}
```

With this approach, on the click, the first thing that you would do is find all of the elements with the class `firstClick` or `secondClick` (based on the value of `click`) and remove the class.  Since there should only ever be one, at the most, that makes for a VERY short loop to go through (but would also remove the class from more than one element, if that were to happen somehow).

**EDIT:**

So, you wouldn't have noticed it in your code, since you don't ever have more than one instance of each of the two classes, but, as **somethingthere** pointed out, we are dealing with a LIVE collection of DOM elements, so, as you remove the classes from the elements (the element that you removed them from, falls out of the collection.

For example, on the third click of your table, there will be one element in the collection that is returned by `document.getElementsByClassName(currClass);` = `HTMLCollection[td.firstClick]` (in the console).  But, once you've removed that class from the element, it no longer matches the criteria, so the collection becomes empty (i.e., `HTMLCollection[]`).

So, while it works for your situation (because it stops on `i = 1` because that is still "not less than" the new length of the collection (which is now 0).

However, in other situations, that might not be the case . . . for example, if there were 2 elements returned, after the first one had its class removed, `i` would change to 1, but the length would also drop to 1 and the loop would stop, without processing the second element.

So the approach really needs to be changed to handle that behavior correctly.  I've done that by changing these lines:

```
    for (i = 0; i < currentlyClickedEls.length; i++) {
        currentlyClickedEls[i].className = "";
```

. . . to these lines:

```
    while (currentlyClickedEls.length > 0) {
        currentlyClickedEls[0].className = "";
```

This way, the element that has it's class removed is always the first one in the collection and the `while` loop checks to make sure that there is still an element in the collection, before it attempts to remove the class.

So, long story, short, when dealing with an HTML Collection, as **somethinghere** pointed out, you are dealing with a live collection of DOM elements, so, if you make a change that would affect an individual elements inclusion in that Collection, it **WILL** update the Collection accordingly and you need to be able to account for that in your code.

Comment: Awesome, that worked properly, I see that #somethinghere and #pointy was also correct in so far as how I was dealing with the HTML collection wrong. Thanks to all of you, it was a collective effort and i appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help.   :)   And, actually, there is a "hiccup" in my code . . . give me a few minutes to get it sorted out.  I'll update here when I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `.getElementsByTagName`, you are not getting back an `array`! You are getting back a *live* `HTMLCollection` element, which contains some other items that you cannot ignore when using a `for.. in` loop. Heres where a `for` loop wil come in handy as your live `HTMLCollection` contains a `length` you can use!

```
/* HTMLCollections come with a length attribute we can use 
 * as every item is numbered, but in a object-style key-value pair */
for(var i = 0; i < tdElements.length; i++){
    /* This was tripping up your code - the `item` function to fetch an
     * element at the index defined in the HTMLCollection*/
    tdElements.item(i).style.backgroundColor = "green"
}
```

This will turn all the backgrounds green. Now you will have to amend your code, but thats how it works. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: - Thank you, I'm trying to get it functional within the if statements, i'll respond shortly.